# No padding between "Browse more questions" and anniversary banner on mobile

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, mobile-chrome

On the five sites that have their [10 year anniversary](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/11/10/five-stack-exchange-sites-are-celebrating-their-ten-year-anniversaries-in-q4-2022/?cb=1) a banner is shown linking to a meta post about the anniversary. On mobile the banner is shown below the question list. However, there is no padding between the <kbd>Browse more Questions</kbd> button and the banner.

Screenshot from [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) with Chrome on Android below. Chrome version is 107.0.0.0, screen size 720x1280 'real pixels'.

[image]

Comment: tried it on my phone on chrome and android 13 and no repro

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I tried on two different phones with Android and they both show it. Maybe related to the screen size? As you can see from the screenshot my own phone is small, the other phone that I tried is bigger but not by much.

Comment: well resolution - and that's worth including in the question

Comment: Just tried it on Edge 107.0.1418.35 on Windows 10 with a really narrow window, and I was able to reproduce the situation.